# How to get a List of model from List<Task<Model>>?

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

I have this method:

```
public async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
{
    var result = await GetMatches();
    var toList = result.OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedAt)
        .Select(async p => new CardDataModel()
        {
            HeadTitle = await generateHeadTitle(p) ,
            HeadLines = p.Sport + " - " + p.PlayersNeeded + " players needed    @" + p.Location,
            HeadLinesDesc = p.Comment,
            ProfileImage = "Person_7.jpg"
        }).ToList();

    CardList = toList;
}
```

Which should generate me a List but because i'm using async/await i'm getting a `List<Task<CardDataModel>>` which I cannot bind to a my List property .

Any ideas how to get the desired List ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns turns an `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` into a `Task<T[]>` that way you can then await it and then use `ToList` to get a `List`, like this:

```
CardDataModel[] modelArray = await Task.WhenAll(toList);
CardList = modelArray.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helpful extension method to add to the already provided answer.

```
public static class Ex {
    public static Task<T[]> WhenAll<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks) {
        return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

and used like

```
var result = await GetMatches();
var toList = await result.OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedAt)
    .Select(async p => new CardDataModel() {
        HeadTitle = await generateHeadTitle(p),
        HeadLines = p.Sport + " - " + p.PlayersNeeded + " players needed    @" + p.Location,
        HeadLinesDesc = p.Comment,
        ProfileImage = "Person_7.jpg"
    })
    .WhenAll();

CardList = toList.ToList();
```